# regex to include pipes

Tags: regex, grep

file:

```
one|two|three|peter01|five|six
one|peter01|three|four|five|six
```

output:

```
one|two|three|peter01|five|six
```

how to grep peter01 in the 4th field only?

I tried:

```
egrep "^*\|*\|*\|peter01\|*$"
```

but no luck !

Answer (score 2):

Does it have to be `grep`? This is a good use of `awk`:

```
awk -F'\|' '$4 == "peter01"'
```

The problem with your regexp is that you're missing something before `*`. It should be:

```
egrep '^[^|]*\|[^|]*\|[^|]*\|peter01\|'
```

Comment: thanks, it works, inside perl, I need to remove the backslases, no need to escape, thanks again

Comment: If using `egrep` then would be good to use RE Interval as well. `egrep '^([^|]*\|){3}peter01\|' file`